# Popup Terms and Conditions in VB.NET with a return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I'm trying to accomplish the following scenario:

1. I click on Add Friend button.
2. A pop up appears says "In order to add friends ... check the box below then click yes"
3. Until I check the box, yes was disabled
4. I check the box and click Yes
5. Popup closes, previous browser window gets redirected.
6. While pop up is active I cannot use the previous window.

Alternate scenario:
4. I click No
5. Popup window closes, nothing happens to previous page, not even a postback.

I'm not sure if something like this would be possible.

I have tried playing with:

```
window.open("TermsAndConditions.html", "", "height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0");
```

But I can't get the page redirected after I close that window, further more users can navigate away and open infinite pop ups just by clicking the button over and over again.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Use the 'yes' button clicked as an event to redirect the page and disable the T&C button if the windows loads/the button is clicked.

Comment: Instead of using a pop-up window you could just have a DIV span the entire area of the window to block access to the page, and another DIV centered on top of that one with the terms and conditions, checkbox, and yes button. When they click yes, set the div to invisible and then redirect your page. I use this same method for creating custom message boxes all the time, works like a charm.